# What happens when WebClientProtocol Timeout occurs

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, timeout

We have a client application that has reference to a webservice. We had set the timeout property on the webclientprotocol object to 50 (ms) and wanted to observe what goes on. We tied up a long running webmethod that returns a huge DataSet to the client. When the default value was there, the DataSet was returned properly to the client. When we changed this to 50(ms), we did not observe anything. Our assumption was that there would be some kind of exception that occurs on the client side since the timeout has occurred. Can anyone please explain what is going on here

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is unfortunately unclear. When you say you "didn't observe anything" what exactly do you mean? Did the code hang forever? Was an exception thrown? Presumaby a valid DataSet wasn't returned.

I would *expect* a [TimeoutException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timeoutexception.aspx) to be thrown but I'm surprised that wasn't entirely obvious in your client code. You're not swallowing exceptions, are you?

Are you executing the call synchronously or asynchronously? If it's asynchronous, I'd expect the callback to be executed and then the exception to be thrown on the "EndXxx" call.

I strongly recommend that you write a short console application which *just* calls the web service, just to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this.  In a .NET 2.0 Web service, it throws a pretty unspecific `WebException`, with only the `Message` property to distinguish it:

> The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

I haven't tried it in the WCF-based service references generated by default in newer versions of Visual Studio, but if I understand [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/sujithkjagini/archive/2009/08/24/timeout-exceptions.aspx) correctly, they throw a more useful `TimeoutException`, which, like [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362042/what-happens-when-webclientprotocol-timeout-occurs/362093#362093), I would have guessed (and would prefer) to be the behavior in a Web service.

Note that the timeout is only for synchronous calls (at least in a Web service; I think it's true for a WCF service reference, too).  If you want an asynchronous call to time out, you'll have to set a timer and abort the call manually, such as demonstrated [here](http://spinningtheweb.blogspot.com/2011/02/async-web-service-timout.html).

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. Also, did you look in the `InnerException` property?

Comment: @John Saunders: The question was, "What happens when WebClientProtocol Timeout occurs?"  The answer is, "It throws a WebException."  How does that not answer the question?  And yes, I looked at the `InnerException` property, hoping to find a `TimeoutException` exception there.  Unfortunately, it was null.  That was part of why only the message text distinguished the exception from other possible WebExceptions.  It's frustrating when a property that's meant only for human consumption must be used for programmatic decisions.